# Spacemacs - SPC is not working

Tags: emacs, spacemacs

I just installed Spacemacs on Ubuntu and key SPC it not working. When I press it, Spacemacs shows the message

`Buffer is read-only: #<buffer *spacemacs*>`

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 and and Emacs 24.

Should i configure anything else? I'm have been following this link https://gist.github.com/shaybix/4dd95830909daa59207635951a533127

Comment: The `*spacemacs*` buffer probably *is*  read-only. Does it work with a different buffer, like `*scratch*` or a newly-visited one?

Comment: maybe you set the editing style to `emacs` instead of `vim`, what happens if you do `M-m`?

Answer (score 6):

`SPC` is for `vim editor style`. Use `M-m` for `emacs editor style`

Comment: should i learn the M-m or learn SPC.      M-m is a bit hard to do. but i am a beginner  to this, so whatever ill learn will become a habit . And if i can use space how to do that.

Comment: i would suggest vim because you would end up using a lot of vim anyway.. but getting hold of either is a great experience.

Comment: I would also add that on emacs **"M" means meta** and generally is the "esc" key. So "M-m" is in reality "esc + m" combination.